# Aws spot instances using run-instances. How to prevent automatic restart after termination?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am creating ec2 Spot instances using the command
aws ec2 run-instances.
I can see that the instances are terminated and restarted by aws.
How can i make sure that if the instance is terminated by aws it does not get restarted by aws (i wish them to stay terminated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options for `SpotInstanceType`: `one-time` and `persistent`.

You should use `one-time`, which means that the Spot Instance will not be restarted.

See: [run-instances — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html)